# Minimum number of coins for a given sum and denominations

Tags: dynamic-programming, coin-change

Given a set of denominations and the sum required I have to find the minimum number of coins that make that sum and **also the number of coins for each denominations**

Please help!!

Answer (score 4):

The pseudo-code to determine minimum number of coins needed to make that sum is:

```
Procedure coinChange(coins, total):
n := coins.length
dp[n][total + 1]
for i from 0 to n
    dp[i][0] := 0
end for
for i from 1 to (total + 1)
    dp[0][i] := i
end for
for i from 1 to n
    for j from 1 to (total + 1)
        if coins[i] > j                 //if the denomination is greater than total
            dp[i][j] := dp[i-1][j] 
        else                           //if the denomination is less than or equal to total
            dp[i][j] := min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-coins[i]])
        end if
    end for
end for
Return dp[n-1][total]
```

And to find out the denominations needed:

```
Procedure printChange(coins, dp, total):
i := coins.length - 1
j := total
min := dp[i][j]
while j is not equal to 0
    if dp[i-1][j] is equal to min          //if the value came from the top we didn't choose current coin
        i := i - 1
    else
        Print(coins[i])
        j := j - coins[i]
    end if
end while
```

If you want to print the number of each denomination, just after printing the `coins[i]`, you need to print the difference of `dp[j]` and `dp[j - coins[i]]`. The rest of the code will be same.

The full description of this solution used to be found in SO Docs, but has now been moved here.

---

## Coin Changing Problem

### Minimum number of coins to get total

Given coins of different denominations and a total, how many coins do we need to combine to get the total if we use minimum number of coins? Let's say we have `coins = {1, 5, 6, 8}` and a `total = 11`, we can get the total using **2** coins which is `{5, 6}`. This is indeed the minimum number of coins required to get **11**. We'll also assume that there are unlimited supply of coins. We're going to use dynamic programming to solve this problem.

We'll use a 2D array **dp[n][total + 1]** where **n** is the number of different denominations of coins that we have. For our example, we'll need **dp[4][12]**. Here **dp[i][j]** will denote the minimum number of coins needed to get **j** if we had coins from **coins[0]** up to **coins[i]**. For example **dp[1][2]** will store if we had **coins[0]** and **coins[1]**, what is the minimum number of coins we can use to make **2**. Let's begin:

At first, for the **0**th column, can make **0** by not taking any coins at all. So all the values of **0**th column will be **0**. For **dp[0][1]**, we are asking ourselves if we had only **1** denomination of coin, that is **coins[0]** = **1**, what is the minimum number of coins needed to get **1**? The answer is **1**. For **dp[0][2]**, if we had only **1**, what is the minimum number of coins needed to get **2**. The answer is **2**. Similarly **dp[0][3]** = **3**, **dp[0][4]** = **4** and so on. One thing to mention here is that, if we didn't have a coin of denomination **1**, there might be some cases where the total can't be achieved using **1** coin only. For simplicity we take **1** in our example. After first iteration our **dp** array will look like:

```
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 (denom)|   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11|
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    (1) | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11|
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    (5) | 1 | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    (6) | 2 | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    (8) | 3 | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Moving on, for **dp[1][1]**, we are asking ourselves if we had **coins[0]** = **1** and **coins[1]** = **5**, what is the minimum number of coins needed to get **1**? Since **coins[1]** is greater than our current total, it will not affect our calculation. We'll need to exclude **coins[5]** and get **1** using **coins[0]** only. This value is stored in **dp[0][1]**. So we take the value from the top. Our first formula is:

```
if coins[i] > j
    dp[i][j] := dp[i-1][j]
```

This condition will be true until our total is **5** in **dp[1][5]**, for that case, we can make **5** in two ways:
 - We take **5** denominations of **coins[0]**, which is stored on **dp[0][5]** (from the top).
 - We take **1** denomination of **coins[1]** and (**5** - **5**) = **0** denominations of **coins[0]**.

We'll choose the minimum of these two. So **dp[1][5]** = min(**dp[0][5]**, **1** + **dp[1][0]**) = **1**. Why did we mention **0** denominations of **coins[0]** here will be apparent in our next position.

For **dp[1][6]**, we can make **6** in two ways:
 - We take **6** denominations of **coins[0]**, which is stored on the top.
 - We can take **1** denomination of **5**, we'll need **6** - **5** = **1** to get the total. The minimum number of ways to get **1** using the coins of denomination **1** and **5** is stored in **dp[1][1]**, which can be written as **dp[i][j-coins[i]]**, where **i** = **1**. This is why we wrote the previous value in that fashion.

We'll take the minimum of these two ways. So our second formula will be:

```
if coins[i] >= j
    dp[i][j] := min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-coins[i]])
```

Using these two formulae we can fill up the whole table. Our final result will be:

```
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 (denom)|   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11|
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    (1) | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11|
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    (5) | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    (6) | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    (8) | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Our required result will be stored at **dp[3][11]**. The procedure will be:

```
Procedure coinChange(coins, total):
n := coins.length
dp[n][total + 1]
for i from 0 to n
    dp[i][0] := 0
end for
for i from 1 to (total + 1)
    dp[0][i] := i
end for
for i from 1 to n
    for j from 1 to (total + 1)
        if coins[i] > j
            dp[i][j] := dp[i-1][j] 
        else
            dp[i][j] := min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-coins[i]])
        end if
    end for
end for
Return dp[n-1][total]
```

The runtime complexity of this algorithm is: O(n*total) where **n** is the number of denominations of coins.

To print the coins needed, we need to check:
 - if the value came from top, then the current coin is not included.
 - if the value came from left, then the current coin is included.

The algorithm would be:

```
Procedure printChange(coins, dp, total):
i := coins.length - 1
j := total
min := dp[i][j]
while j is not equal to 0
    if dp[i-1][j] is equal to min
        i := i - 1
    else
        Print(coins[i])
        j := j - coins[i]
    end if
end while
```

For our example, the direction will be:

[image: Direction Array]

The values will be **6**, **5**.

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 typos in the code :

first :

```
if coins[i] >= j 
    dp[i][j] := min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-coins[i]])
```

this should be :

```
 if coins[i] > j <-- HERE
        dp[i][j] := min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-coins[i]])
```

second : also in the same previous code, the second part of the min is missing + 1 
so the correct code would be

```
if coins[i] > j
        dp[i][j] := min(dp[i-1][j], 1 + dp[i][j-coins[i]]) <-- HERE
```

third :

```
while j is not equal to 0
    if dp[i-1][j] is equal to min
        i := i - 1
    else
        Print(coins[i])
        j := j - coins[I] 
      // <---- HERE
    end if
end while
```

in here we should reassign the min to the new cell , so the correct code would be :

```
while j is not equal to 0
    if dp[i-1][j] is equal to min
        i := i - 1
    else
        Print(coins[i])
        j := j - coins[I]
        min = dp[I][j]    
    end if
end while
```

Many thanks for the solution.